# how to make it so the space inbetween buttons can't be highlighted

Tags: javascript, html, css

html:

```html
<button id='automoney' onclick='minusTen()'></button>
<button id='automoney2' onclick='minusHundred()'></button>
<button id='automoney3' onclick='minusFiveHundred()'></button>
<button id='automoney4' onclick='minusThousand()'></button>
<button id='automoney5' onclick='minusFifteenHundred()'></button>
<button id='automoney6' onclick='minusThreeThousand()'></button>
```

the space between the buttons can be highlighted. if there is a way to do it using CSS, that would be preferable, if not, that's fine too

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping buttons into flex div to remove spaces.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button id='automoney' onclick='minusTen()'></button>
    <button id='automoney2' onclick='minusHundred()'></button>
    <button id='automoney3' onclick='minusFiveHundred()'></button>
    <button id='automoney4' onclick='minusThousand()'></button>
    <button id='automoney5' onclick='minusFifteenHundred()'></button>
    <button id='automoney6' onclick='minusThreeThousand()'></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add css flex property to your div or float it and remove all white spaces, then add margin to the buttons to add space that is not delectable.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}
button {
  margin: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button id='automoney' onclick='minusTen()'></button>
    <button id='automoney2' onclick='minusHundred()'></button>
    <button id='automoney3' onclick='minusFiveHundred()'></button>
    <button id='automoney4' onclick='minusThousand()'></button>
    <button id='automoney5' onclick='minusFifteenHundred()'></button>
    <button id='automoney6' onclick='minusThreeThousand()'></button>
</div>
```